# Почему POST запрос к Яндекс API для изменения DNS записи (А) выдаёт ошибку?

Tags: c#, post, dns, яндекс-почта

Поиском пользовался.
Ошибка:

```
{"error": "no_domain", "success": "error"}
```

При этом GET работают (например запрос на DNS-записи этого же домена).
Метод запроса:

```
public static void RefreshARecord(string ip)
    {
        string domain = "domain.ru";
        string record_id = "000000";
        string admin_mail = "adminmail@yandex.ru";
        string content = ip;

        string requestString = String.Format("domain={0}&record_id={1}&admin_mail={2}&content={3}",
            domain, record_id, admin_mail, content);

        //Получаем массив байт для записи в поток запроса
        byte[] reqStringArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);

        //Объект запроса
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://pddimp.yandex.ru/api2/admin/dns/edit");
        req.Headers.Add("PddToken", pddToken);
        req.Host = "pddimp.yandex.ru";
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        req.ContentLength = reqStringArray.Length;

        //Запись данных в запрос
        using (Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(reqStringArray, 0, reqStringArray.Length);
            dataStream.Flush();
        }

        HttpWebResponse resp =  (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте установить заголовок `ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. Также я бы на вашем месте использовал `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` для кодирования строки запроса в грамотный формат.  Ну а вообще, советую отказаться от `HttpWebRequest` вовсе, ибо он уже давно признан устаревшим и нежелателен для новых разработок.

Comment: Ееее)) Заголовок ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" помог) Спасибо) Только не знаю как указать что Ваш ответ помог

Comment: Ну раз помогло, то напишите сами ответ с тем, что вы сделали. Но про совет отказаться от `HttpWebRequest` подумайте все же пока не поздно.

Comment: Буду смотреть варианты. Сейчас главное собрать хоть что то в защиту от динамического IP. А в какую сторону смотреть для ухода от HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Загляните в документацию самих Microsoft, посмотрите описание `HttpWebRequest`, увидите `Важно! Не рекомендуется использовать HttpWebRequest для новой разработки. Вместо этого используйте класс System.Net.Http.HttpClient.`

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы. С HttpClient гораздо меньше сложностей и код более читаем. Ещё раз спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помог совет [EvgeniyZ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220553/evgeniyz) в комментарии под вопросом. А конкретно `ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. Спасибо

> Попробуйте установить заголовок `ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. Также я бы на вашем месте использовал `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` для кодирования строки запроса в грамотный формат. Ну а вообще, советую отказаться от `HttpWebRequest` вовсе, ибо он уже давно признан устаревшим и нежелателен для новых разработок.

PS: Переделал код на `HttpClient` библиотеку, но столкнулся с той же ошибкой. Оказалось при реализации через консоль, данные надо кодировать через `FormUrlEncodedContent` и всё работает.